# Flask: How to redirect on clicking an autocomplete entry by JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, flask, autocomplete

Here is the code snippets. I have a form like this

```
<form class="form-inline md-form form-sm my-0">
    <input id="search_query" name="search_query" class="form-control form-control-sm mr-3 w-95"
        type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
</form>
```

and I want to autocomplete my search query via a flask view:

```
@bp_main.route("/autocomplete", methods=["GET"])
def autocomplete():
    query = request.args.get("q", type=str)
    items = get_search_results(query=query)
    results = [{"value": item.id, "label": item.name} for item in items]
    return jsonify(matching_results=results)
```

Here's the js part:

```
$(document).ready(function {
    $(function () {
        $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.getJSON("{{ url_for('main.autocomplete') }}", {
                    q: request.term, // in flask, "q" will be the argument to look for using request.args
                }, function (data) {
                    response(data.matching_results); // matching_results from jsonify
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                console.log(ui.item.value); // not in your question, but might help later
            }
        });
    });
});
```

For now I'm able to get the autocomplete dropdown list as I search. But I couldn't figure out how to send a get request to another view and direct. The view has got one named parameter only, which should be exactly what the input form get from user click. So basically the user click `item.label`, and then the app feed the corresponding `item.id` to that view and render it. Just like how any searches works today. I have no clue which parts I'm missing.